# Unity - Why does this only work inside the if statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im having an issue with moving my character.

The following code works.

```
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            // X/Z Movement
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;
            // Y Movement.
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = jumpForce;
        }
        // Apply gravity.
        moveDirection.y -= grav * Time.deltaTime;
        // Move the player.
        print(moveDirection);
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
```

However if I move everything between the X/Z Movement and Y Movement comments before the if statement, the player will only fall by a small amount rather than it increasing the longer they are in the air. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: have you tried stepping through it in debug and seeing what happens when it hits the if statement? is jumpForce getting called?

Comment: Nevermind I found out why. Its because Im resetting moveDirection.y every loop of Update so instead of stacking up gravity, its resetting to 0 and then applying -= grav * Time.deltatime

Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. Its because Im resetting moveDirection.y every loop of Update so instead of stacking up gravity, its resetting to 0 and then applying -= grav * Time.deltatime

Answer (score 0):

I acutally had the same questions a few weeks ago and I think I can help:
The actual 'problem' you see comes from here :

`moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));`

If the player is grounded there is no reason to move him on Y axis, so it's value is 0, but if you move it outside of Update, it keeps reseting each frame.

Now this line: `moveDirection.y -= grav * Time.deltaTime;` substracts from a Vector3 with 0 on the Y and not from the moveVector's Y created from `moveDirection.y = jumpForce;`

Hope this helps.